# GeneratedValue strategy in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to add sequence number in my table using hibernate Generated Value strategy. I already have numbers 1 and 2 in my table's column and now I want to start my number generation from 3.

Which type should I use to meet this requirement? Can I do that? Or will hibernate only start from number 0 in all cases?

```
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the TABLE strategy is used, it will start with the current value stored in the table used for ID generation the corresponds to the entity.

If the SEQUENCE strategy is used, it will start with the current value of the sequence.

If the IDENTITY strategy is used, it will ask the next ID to the database (the column should be auto incremented), and the database shouldn't return an aready used ID.

Comment: Are you saying that by using Sequence strategy, the hibernate will generate the next number based on the current value that is assigned as the primary key?

Comment: So if i use table then it will consider my max id number? and add next number when i insert a row in that same table?

Comment: @Zeus: no. I'm saying it uses the sequence to generate IDs, and that the current value of the sequence drives what the next ID will be, an not the biggest ID of the table.

Comment: @PratikJoshi: no. The table strategy uses a specific table to store values used to generate next IDs (one row for each entity). The values in this table is what matters.